# JavaScript function to display records from SQL Server based on input date values

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I am trying to create a rentals website. There is provision to input the start date and enddate and I have to fetch records from SQL Server matching the criteria. There is a table called Bookings which stores start date and end date of Apartment bookings. In order to display Apartment records with no corresponding booking in the given time range, how can I proceed with the JavaScript function?

I have something like this right now. The select query seems to be missing something.

```
function searchDB() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    Select * from Apartments where Id NOT IN (SELECT ApartmentId from Bookings where start >= StartDate  and end <= EndDate);
  }
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a connection to the database?

Comment: Hi @DaleK, I have added the config file separately and in the js file added the following.
`const 
config = {
    user :'admin',
    password :'******',
    server:'*********************',
    database:'RentalDB',
    options:{
        trustedconnection: true,
        enableArithAbort : true, 
        instancename :'awsrds'
    },
    port : 1433
}

module.exports = config;`

Answer (score 1):

You need have a REST API which will connect to the SQL SERVER database fetches the data, The REST API end point should be invoked from Frontend javascript code using AJAX or Fetch API.